# QList default parameter error message (default argument for QList<QVariant> has type int)

Tags: c++, qt, methods, parameters, default-parameters

I have the following method ( which has just 1 parameter) that I want to adapt to use for more than 1 parameters. I tried to use default parameters but this doesn't work. ( The original code with just the old method works fine) What strikes me is that the variable name omitted in that daclaration. **Why ?**

This is my original method:

```
void importFile(QString *);
```

That is my new method:

```
 void importFile(QString *, QList<QVariant> IMPORT_FILE_PARAMETERS =0 );
```

When I compile this code Qt tells me " *default argument for QList IMPORT_FILE_PARAMETERS has type int*

**What is the problem?
I don´t use int - Why would he tell me about int?**

Thanks for your help

Comment: In the declaration - it's just not needed, the compiler only needs the type, putting a name there is just for human readability.  In the C++ file - if you don't use the variable, you won't get a warning for unused variable.

Comment: Your title has little to do with the question you seem to be asking. But it would be easier if you asked a single question.

Comment: Consider overloading instead of using default parameters. Unless your code runs exactly the same, irregardless of whether or not `IMPORT_FILE_PARAMETERS` is default constructed, this is most likely the cleaner approach.

Answer (score 5):

```
QList<QVariant> IMPORT_FILE_PARAMETERS =0
```

This makes no sense. You give `0` (which is an `int`, as in your error message) as a default parameter for a `QList`, try to make it a default constructed list instead :

```
QList<QVariant> IMPORT_FILE_PARAMETERS = QList<QVariant>()
```

As for

> What strikes me ist that the variable name omitted in that
>   daclaration. Why ?

The compiler doesn't care about the name at all in the declaration, it only needs to know the parameter types. You can omit it in the definition of the function too but then you can't access the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Your default parameter is "0", which is an integer, right?

Use this:

```
void importFile(QString *, QList<QVariant> IMPORT_FILE_PARAMETERS = QList<QVariant>());
```

This will make the default parameter an empty `QList`.

Answer (score 1):

QList is not an int
You are trying to assign a value 0 (zero) which is an int to that type.